# Slow initial connection to API

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, profiling

I've got an API written in C# (webforms) and an SQL Server 2008 database that accepts JSON POST data on an AWS EC2 VM. My problem is that the "first" use of this API is rather slow to respond.

What I mean by "first" is that if I were to wait for an hour or so, then post some data, that would be the first. Subsequent posts would process rather quickly in comparison, and I would need to wait another hour or so before experiencing the slow "first" transaction again.

Since only the initial post is slow, it makes me wonder if something is "spinning down" after being idle for some time, and then spinning up again upon first use, adding the extra time.

Things I have tried -

- Run program through a performance profiler - This didn't really help. As far as I can see, the program itself doesn't have any obvious parts that run very slowly or inefficiently.
- Change configuration to persist at least 1 connection to the database at all times. Again, no real change. I did this by adding "Min Pool Size=1;Max Pool Size=100" to my connection string.
- Change configuration to use named pipes instead of TCP. Once again, no real change. I did this by adding "np:" before the server specified in my connection string, eg. server=np:MyServer;database=MyDatabase;

Is there anything else I can do to diagnose the problem? What else should I be looking for in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are your app pool is shutting down after a designated period of non-use. The first call after the shutdown forces everything to get loaded back into memory which explains the lag.

You could play with these settings: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx to see if you get the desired effect, or setup a task scheduler job that makes at least one call every 10+/- minutes of so by doing a simulated post - a simple powershell script could handle that for you and will keep everything 'primed' for the next use.